# How to instruct Doctrine's migration tools to ignore a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Per the [documents](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.0/reference/generating-migrations.html#ignoring-custom-tables), one can instruct Doctrine to ignore one or more tables so that the migration tools will not complain about the database being out of sync.  How can one instruct Doctrine's migration tools to ignore a foreign key constraint?

Reason for asking is that I will have a Doctrine ignored table with its primary key containing allowed values for a given column in a Doctrine managed table, and I wish to keep the foreign key in the Doctrine managed table back to the non-Doctrine managed constraints table.